# Error: Unexpected eof Export default sidebar^ Caused by: failed to process js file, syntax error

Tags: tailwind-css

The error I am getting is Error: Unexpected eof
Export default sidebar^
Caused by: failed to process js file, syntax error.

I am using Tailwindcss on localhost:3000
Trying to build a clone of the Twitter app from a YouTube Tutorial, and I am stuck here.
I do not know what I am missing?

Here is the code...

```
import { FiMoreHorizontal } from 'react-icons/fi' 
import { VscTwitter } from 'react-icons/vsc' 
import {SidebarOption} from './SidebarOption'
import { useState } from 'react'
import { RiHome7Line, RiHome7Line, RiFileList2Fill} from 'react-icons'
import { BiHash} from 'react-icons/bi'
import { FiBell } from 'react-icons/fi'
import { HiOutlineMail, HiMail} from 'react-icons/fi'
import { FaRegListAlt, FaHashtag, FaBell} from 'react-icons/fa'
import { CgMoreO,} from 'react-icons/cg'
import { text } from 'stream/consumers'


const style = {
    wrapper: 'flex-[0.7] px-8 flex flex-col',                                      
    twitterIconContainer: 'text-3xl m-4',                            
    tweetButton: 'bg-[#1d9bf0] hover:bg-[#1b8cd8] flex items-center justify-center font-bold rounded-3xl h-[50px] mt-[20px] cursor-pointer',
    navContainer: 'flex-1',
    profileButton: 'flex items-center mb-6 cursor-pointer',
    profileLeft: 'flex item-center justify-center mr-4',
    profileImage: 'height-12 w-12 rounded-full ',
    profileRight: 'flex-1 flex',
    details: 'flex-1',
    name: 'text-lg',
    handle: 'text-[#8899a6]',
    moreContainer: 'flex items-center mr-2',
}

function Sidebar({initialSelectedIcon= 'Home'}){
    const [selected, setSelected] = useState(initialSelectedIcon)
    return (
        <div className ={style.wrapper}>
        <div className ={style.twitterIconContainer}>
            <VscTwitter/>
   </div>
        <div className ={style.navContainer}>
    <SidebarOption 
            Icon = {selected = 'Home'? RiHome7Fill : RiHome7Line}
            text = 'Home' 
            isActive = {Boolean(selected = 'Home')}
            setSelected = {setSelected} 
            redirect = {'/'} 
       />
        
       <SidebarOption 
            Icon = {selected = 'Explore'? FaHashtag : BiHash}
            text = "Explore" 
            isActive = {Boolean(selected = 'Explore')}
            setSelected = {setSelected} 
       /> 
       <SidebarOption
            Icon = {selected = 'Profile'? BsPersonFill : BsPerson}
            text = "Profile" 
            isActive = {Boolean(selected = 'Profile')}
            setSelected = {setSelected} 
            redirect = {'/profile'} 
            />
       <div>More</div>
        <div className = {style.tweetButton}>Mint</div>
       </div>
        <div className={style.profileButton}>
        <div className={style.profileLeft}></div>
        <div className={style.profileRight}>
        <div className={style.details}>
        <div className={style.name}>dustinCar</div>
        <div className={style.handle}>@dusto69</div>
        </div>
        <div className= {style.moreContainer}>
            <FiMoreHorizontal/>
        </div> 
        </div>
        
    )
}
export default Sidebar
```

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the two missing `</div>` at the end. Also missing `;` at the export default stmt.

Use this

```
function Sidebar({ initialSelectedIcon = 'Home' }) {
    const [selected, setSelected] = useState(initialSelectedIcon)
    return (
        <div className={style.wrapper}>
            <div className={style.twitterIconContainer}>
                <VscTwitter />
            </div>
            <div className={style.navContainer}>
                <SidebarOption
                    Icon={selected = 'Home' ? RiHome7Fill : RiHome7Line}
                    text='Home'
                    isActive={Boolean(selected = 'Home')}
                    setSelected={setSelected}
                    redirect={'/'}
                />

                <SidebarOption
                    Icon={selected = 'Explore' ? FaHashtag : BiHash}
                    text="Explore"
                    isActive={Boolean(selected = 'Explore')}
                    setSelected={setSelected}
                />
                <SidebarOption
                    Icon={selected = 'Profile' ? BsPersonFill : BsPerson}
                    text="Profile"
                    isActive={Boolean(selected = 'Profile')}
                    setSelected={setSelected}
                    redirect={'/profile'}
                />
                <div>More</div>
                <div className={style.tweetButton}>Mint</div>
            </div>
            <div className={style.profileButton}>
                <div className={style.profileLeft}></div>
                <div className={style.profileRight}>
                    <div className={style.details}>
                        <div className={style.name}>dustinCar</div>
                        <div className={style.handle}>@dusto69</div>
                    </div>
                    <div className={style.moreContainer}>
                        <FiMoreHorizontal />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
export default Sidebar;
```